# Create Intervals from start-end date and represent all the values - comma separated

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONS (
    PERSON_UID    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    PERSON_NAME   VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE SKILLS (
    SKILL_UID    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    SKILL_NAME   VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE PERSON_SKILLS (
    PERSON_SKILLS_UID   NUMBER,
    PERSON_FK           NUMBER,
    SKILL_FK            NUMBER,
    VALID_START         DATE,
    VAID_END            DATE
);
```

Table data:

### PERSONS table data

> ```
> PERSON_UID | PERSON_NAME
> ---------: | :----------
>          1 | P1         
>          2 | P2         
>          3 | P3
> ```

### SKILLS table data

> ```
> SKILL_UID | SKILL_NAME
> --------: | :---------
>         1 | SKILL1    
>         2 | SKILL2    
>         3 | SKILL3    
>         4 | SKILL4    
>         5 | SKILL5    
>         6 | SKILL6    
>         7 | SKILL7    
>         8 | SKILL8    
>         9 | SKILL9    
>        10 | SKILL10
> ```

### PERSON_SKILLS table data

> ```
> PERSON_SKILLS_UID | PERSON_FK | SKILL_FK | VALID_START | VAID_END   
> ----------------: | --------: | -------: | :---------- | :----------
>                 1 |         1 |        1 | 01-JAN-1990 | null       
>                 2 |         1 |        2 | 01-JAN-1990 | 25-SEP-2001
>                 4 |         1 |        6 | 01-JAN-1990 | 01-JAN-2010
>                 5 |         1 |        7 | 01-JAN-1990 | null       
>                 3 |         1 |        3 | 01-JUL-1990 | null       
>                 6 |         1 |        9 | 31-DEC-2018 | null       
>                 7 |         2 |        2 | 01-JAN-1990 | null       
>                 9 |         2 |        8 | 01-JAN-1990 | 01-JAN-2001
>                 8 |         2 |        3 | 01-JAN-1995 | 20-OCT-1998
>                10 |         3 |        9 | 01-JAN-1990 | null       
>                11 |         3 |        4 | 01-JAN-1990 | null       
>                12 |         3 |        5 | 01-JAN-1991 | null       
>                13 |         3 |        7 | 01-JAN-2005 | null
> ```

Table PERSON_SKILLS contains the individual skills of a person with a valid start and valid end date. (NULL valid end date represents the SKILL is currently active)

I want to create the date intervals using start/end dates and all the skills (Comma-separated) pertaining to that interval of the employee.

Let's take the example of person 2: (I need output for all the employees in a single query)

### Expected output

> ```
> PERSON_NAME | VALID_START | VALID_END   | SKILLS_OF_EMP         
> :---------- | :---------- | :---------- | :---------------------
> P2          | 01-JAN-1990 | 31-DEC-1994 | SKILL2, SKILL8        
> P2          | 01-JAN-1995 | 20-OCT-1998 | SKILL2, SKILL3, SKILL8
> P2          | 21-OCT-1998 | 01-JAN-2001 | SKILL2, SKILL8        
> P2          | 02-JAN-2001 | 31-DEC-4712 | SKILL2
> ```

I have created the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a894930987882232409bf7254459c7d3) with all table DDL, data and also expected output.

Hoping to find the query which performs faster as I have around 18000 persons with average 15-16 Skills per person.

Note: 31-Dec-4712 is the end of time.

Comment: why is the first valid_end in the expected result `31-DEC-1994 `?

Answer (score 1):

```
with ranges as (
  select per, dt d1, nvl(lead(dt)  over (partition by per order by dt) - 1, date '4712-12-31') d2
    from (select person_fk per, valid_start dt from person_skills union 
          select person_fk, vaid_end from person_skills)  
    where dt is not null)
select per, d1, d2 , listagg(skill_name, ', ') within group (order by d1) list
  from person_skills ps
  join ranges r on (d1<vaid_end or vaid_end is null) and valid_start <= d2 and ps.person_fk = per 
  join persons p on per = p.person_uid
  join skills s on s.skill_uid = ps.skill_fk
  where d1 is not null
  group by per, d1, d2
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b94ec8dce88c9d0bf26466247613ea49)</sup>**

The main problem is to create time ranges for each person. I made union of date_start and date_end (not `union all` because we need distinct values) for each person. Ordered these dates in `lead()` to create periods.

Such prepared table can be joined in typical way with your data, aggregated and `listagg()` finishes the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS` to get the start and end of the date ranges into separate rows and then use the `LEAD` analytic function to find successive boundary dates for each person then you can join back to the main tables and aggregate.

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT p.person_name,
       r.range_start AS valid_start,
       r.range_end AS valid_end,
       LISTAGG( s.skill_name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY s.skill_name ) AS skills_of_emp
FROM   (
  SELECT PERSON_FK,
         date_time AS range_start,
         LEAD( date_time ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PERSON_FK ORDER BY date_time )
           AS range_end
  FROM   (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           PERSON_FK,
           COALESCE( date_time, DATE '4712-12-31' ) AS date_time
    FROM   person_skills
    UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS ( date_time FOR value IN ( valid_start AS 1, valid_end AS -1 ) )
  )
) r
INNER JOIN Person_skills ps
ON (   ps.valid_start <= r.range_start
   AND r.range_end   <= COALESCE( ps.valid_end, DATE '4712-12-31' )
   AND ps.person_fk   = r.person_fk )
INNER JOIN skills s
ON ( ps.skill_fk = s.skill_uid )
INNER JOIN people p
ON ( ps.person_fk = p.person_uid )
GROUP BY r.person_fk,
         p.person_name,
         r.range_start,
         r.range_end
```

**Output**:

> ```
> PERSON_NAME | VALID_START | VALID_END  | SKILLS_OF_EMP                     
> :---------- | :---------- | :--------- | :---------------------------------
> P1          | 1990-01-01  | 1990-07-01 | SKILL1,SKILL2,SKILL6,SKILL7       
> P1          | 1990-07-01  | 2001-09-25 | SKILL1,SKILL2,SKILL3,SKILL6,SKILL7
> P1          | 2001-09-25  | 2010-01-01 | SKILL1,SKILL3,SKILL6,SKILL7       
> P1          | 2010-01-01  | 2018-12-31 | SKILL1,SKILL3,SKILL7              
> P1          | 2018-12-31  | 4712-12-31 | SKILL1,SKILL3,SKILL7,SKILL9       
> P2          | 1990-01-01  | 1995-01-01 | SKILL2,SKILL8                     
> P2          | 1995-01-01  | 1998-10-20 | SKILL2,SKILL3,SKILL8              
> P2          | 1998-10-20  | 2001-01-01 | SKILL2,SKILL8                     
> P2          | 2001-01-01  | 4712-12-31 | SKILL2                            
> P3          | 1990-01-01  | 1991-01-01 | SKILL4,SKILL9                     
> P3          | 1991-01-01  | 2005-01-01 | SKILL4,SKILL5,SKILL9              
> P3          | 2005-01-01  | 4712-12-31 | SKILL4,SKILL5,SKILL7,SKILL9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=271e65e26f0e51cd3689d6cb0e06decc)*